# ng-bootstrap timepicker display format as hh:mm a?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Angular6 project.

I am using this https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples

The output of ngb-timepicker using NgbTimeStruct which is formatted like so

```
{hour: 13, minute: 30};
```

How do I display this as 01:30 PM? I was looking at Pipe Date from angular, but this requires use Javascript Date object... but I do not need Date just the time.

This is my code

html

```
 <ngb-timepicker [formControl]="startCtrl" [meridian]="meridian" [minuteStep]="minuteStep"></ngb-timepicker>
 <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="update()">Update Time</button>
 <div>{{ startTime }}</div>
```

component

```
 startCtrl = new FormControl();

 update(){
  this.starter = this.startCtrl.value;
 }
```

I don't need the date just the time

Comment: In the documentation link you have provided, there is a section "Custom Time Adapter" which has example of using time format HH:mm:ss. That example is using 24h format but it won't be difficult to derive 12h format from that example.

Comment: Hi thanks for this... may I ask... what does `${}` do? is this a typescript syntax?

Comment: It's a javascript syntax called Template literals. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

They have updated their documentation You can find it here.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker#api-reference

Its simple you just have to use the new Date object given by angular and you will be up and running.